# Exclude whitespace from search pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression with `findall()`.  The issue I'm having is that there is an unknown number of whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, carriage returns) in the patterns.

In the example bellow I want to use `findall()` to get the text inside `<D> </D>` whenever an `</A>` is found after the `</D>`.  My problem is that there are whitespace characters after `</D>`.

In the example below I need to retrieve `Second Text`.  The regular expression I have only works in there is no whitespace between `</D>` and `</A>`.  This is what I tried:

```
regex = '<D>(.+?)</D></A>'

<A> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <D> Second Text</D>
</A>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to match the whitespace between `</D>` and `</A>`:

```
regex = r'<D>(.+?)</D>\s*</A>'
```

notice using `r''` raw string literal for regular expressions in python, to avoid double-escaping that would be needed in normal strings:

```
regex = '<D>(.+?)</D>\\s*</A>'
```

and to make `.` to match newlines, you can use the [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag for matching

Answer (score 1):

`\. \* \\`  escaped special characters.

`\t \n \r`  tab, linefeed, carriage return.

`\u00A9`    unicode escaped ©.

For more information, and testing your regex, try this http://regexr.com/.

For what it's worth, in Python, you can also clear your text using `my_string.strip('\t')` or replace them with spaces with `my_string.replace('\t', ' ')`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you try replacing all `tabs` with `spaces`?

Comment: I don't want to use replace everytime I want to find a pattern, it is too much work and complicates things. I am trying to figure out how it can be done with a regular expression.

Comment: Try this: `/.*?().*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+)).*?(<\/D>)/igm` Worked for me on your example.

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing is not always recommended when HTML parsing libs like BeautifulSoup do such a nice job creating a document object representing the HTML page. But sometimes, you don't want the whole document, you just want to pick out snippets.

Regex is a really fragile extractor when scraping web pages, since whitespace can crop up in surprising places, tags sometimes get attributes when you don't expect them to, upper and lower case tag names are acceptable, and so on. Pyparsing's helper method `makeHTMLTags(tagname)` does more than just wrap `<>`s around the input string - it handles all the whitespace, letter case, and attribute variabilities, and still gives you a pretty readable program when you are done.  Downside - pyparsing is not the snappiest in performance.

See the different examples in the input test, and the matches that are found:

```
test = """\
<A> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <D> Second Text</D>
</A>
<A> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <d extra_attribute='something'> another Text</d>
</A>
<A> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <D> yet another Text</D>
   \t\t
</A>
"""

from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, SkipTo, anyOpenTag, lineno, col

# makeHTMLTags will return patterns for both the opening and closing tags
d,d_end = makeHTMLTags('d')
a,a_end = makeHTMLTags('a')

# define the pattern you want to match
pattern = d + SkipTo(d_end, failOn=anyOpenTag)('body') + d_end + a_end

# use scanString to scan the input HTML, and get match,start,end triples
for match, loc, endloc in pattern.scanString(test):
    print '"%s" at line %d, col %d' % (match.body, lineno(loc, test), col(loc, test))
```

prints

```
"Second Text" at line 3, col 4
"another Text" at line 7, col 4
"yet another Text" at line 11, col 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks it is a portion of xml so it is better not to use `regex` here better try `lxml`, `bs4` etc. BTW I tried a hybrid method i.e first select `A` tag and then select text inside `D` in that `A`.

```
import re
#let's take a string i.e. txt that is very roughest string that even doesnot maintain rules of xml

txt = """<A> 


   <B> Text </B> 


   <D> Second Text</D>


</A> line 3\n
<S> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <D> Second Text</D>
</A>
<E> 
   <B> Text </B> 
   <D> Second Text</D>
</A>"""

A = re.findall(r'<A>[\w\W]*?</A>',txt)
print re.findall(r'(?<=<D>)[\w\W]*?(?=</D>)',''.join(A))
```

Output-

```
[' Second Text']
```

See Demo at [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/fG1hK0/1) for the first expression and [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/pD0xH4/2) for second regex